# Visualizing a real drone's path

Tags: odometry, rviz, path, ros3djs, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I would like to visualize a real AR.DRONE 2.0's path with a simple line in a plane grid. My question is which is the simplest method? Should i use Rviz? I found ros3djs javascript library, which has a Path function, but dont really know which node should i pass to the function.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288698/visualizing-a-real-drone%27s-path/) by [hoffa](https://answers.ros.org/users/34648/hoffa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is your best bet here.

There are two common approaches you can choose from, depending on what information your drone publishes.

If your drone publishes its current position estimate relative to a fixed point (such as where it was turned on), then you can display that information directly in rviz by selecting the published position's frame as the fixed frame (under the "global options" header in the left panel).

If your drone publishes a relative offset from its previous position estimate each time, then you will need to create a node that accumulates that value to provide an absolute position estimate, and then publish that for rviz to display.

If you provide more information about what your drone publishes, I can provide more exact instructions.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hoffa](https://answers.ros.org/users/34648/hoffa/) on 2018-04-17**:
Thanks for your answer! The ARDRONE 2.0 publishes its current position estimate relative to a fixed point. With the help of rviz TF i could reproduce the drones position to the 'world', using the odometry data. [link text](https://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading.html#odometry-data)

**Comment by [hoffa](https://answers.ros.org/users/34648/hoffa/) on 2018-04-17**:
Now i'm struggling with the Path option, because i don't find any topic with nav_msgs/Path type to subscribe to.

**Comment by [hoffa](https://answers.ros.org/users/34648/hoffa/) on 2018-04-17**:
I figured it out how to get nav_msgs/Path type from the odometry topic. I could also use the urdf model of the ardrone, and it looks amazing! [Pic](https://imgur.com/a/Xlwdn)

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-04-17**:
If your problem is solved, then please mark the answer as a solution so that others with the same problem know it works.

**Comment by [FrancinaCarron](https://answers.ros.org/users/75581/francinacarron/) on 2021-07-11**:
Hi! Can I ask how did you do it? Because I'm having the same problem and I can't find the way to solve it. I already made a node that converts tha odometry data to the path type but it doesn't work. I don't know how to get the drone's urdf either.
Would yo help me, please?